# Disable specific assembly in ngen

Tags: c#, c++-cli, pdb-files, ngen

When running ngen on an executable (.exe), is it possible to disable ngen for a specific assembly only?

Details:
The assembly is a managed C++ wrapper that statically links to a native C++ lib file. We distribute the assembly with a stripped down PDB file, to get call stacks from customers, which we can then match up with the full PDB file, when sent to us via an error reporting tool.

Running ngen on this assembly causes this matching process to fail.